# How can I tell caret package to load its dependencies from a different location other than default?

Tags: r, package, r-caret

I am using caret package in R and I was able to install using the command

```
install.packages("caret", lib="C:/My_Packages")
```

Now, when I do a library("caret") in my R script, it complains that it does not find the ggplot package. I had in fact installed ggplot2 using the above syntax.

It seems that the caret tries to load ggplot from the default location and does not search inside "C:/My_Packages".

Is there a way to mention that I want caret to load its dependencies from any other location except the default location?

Answer (score 0):

Yes although this is not an issue with `caret`.

See [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) on `.libPaths`